# Return 0 with dates having empty results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to count offer redemptions for every day over the last 30 days. I want to return a zero if there are no redeemed offers on that particular date for that offer type.

```
SELECT
    a.offertype,
    CONVERT(date,b.[date]) ,
    COUNT( a.offertype )
FROM [dbo].[Last30days] b
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Offers] a ON CONVERT(date,b.[date]) = CONVERT(date,a.[RedeemedDate])
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[UniqueOffers] c ON a.offertype = c.OfferType
WHERE CONVERT(date,[RedeemedDate]) >= CONVERT(date,GETDATE()-30)
GROUP BY
    a.offertype,
    CONVERT(date,b.[date]) 
ORDER BY 
    a.offertype,
    CONVERT(date,b.[date])
```

[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eFNc.png)

- Last30day table > has a date for each day for the last 30 days
- UniqueOffers table > has every distinct offer in the offers table
- offers > has the offer type and the date of redemption

Comment: Please don't post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data, sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/). See the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please show a few lines of each table, as text

Comment: Ideally you want to avoid any `convert`s in your joins and where clause because they can be quite detrimental for performance.